# Ebean Model class in subproject not enhanced

Tags: ebean, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to connect a simple application to two databases, the application has a subproject.
the model for the default database is in the main project while the model for the second database is in the subproject, like so;

```
root/app/models/MainModel
root/sub/app/mods/SubModel
```

now i configure the application.conf like so;

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
#db.default.user=sa
#db.default.password=""

db.sub.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.sub.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
db.sub.username= postgres
db.sub.password="password@1"

ebean.default = ["models.*"]
ebean.sub = ["mods.*"]
```

(yes i use postgre as the second db)
and the build.sbt like so

```
lazy val sub = project.in(file("sub")).enablePlugins(PlayEbean, PlayEnhancer)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
.aggregate(sub)
.dependsOn(sub)
playEbeanModels in Compile := Seq("models.*", "mods.*")
```

root/app/models/MainModel:

```
package models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class MainModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public String name;

}
```

and root/sub/app/mods/SubModel:

```
package mods;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class SubModel extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;
}
```

but when i run the application i get this exception;

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors: 1)
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Bean class mods.SubModel is not enhanced?
```

apparently the model in the root project is enhanced but the model in the sub-project is not. What am i missing? how do i get this to work?

Comment: btw i use play 2.4.3

Comment: Can you post the SubModel class? How is it created? Or create a sample app to reproduce the error (you can place it on github)? Otherwise I have to (manually) build an entire sample app..

Comment: i've updated the question to reflect the models.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Half of my models were in my sub module. I put their ebean config in the application.conf of the sub module.

You should put the line below in the sub/conf/application.conf :

```
ebean.sub = ["mods.*"]
```

and then add the line below in your sub/build.sbt :

```
playEbeanModels in Compile := Seq("mods.*")
```